# WordPress CMS Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, content-management-system

I remember seeing a plugin for WordPress that allowed you to have blocks of content within pages, but can't remember the name. Anyone know which one it is?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need something simple you can use conditional statements to add blocks of content to specific or all pages:

```
if ( is_page('42') ) {
    // here goes the code
}
```

This will insert the code at page 42.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be [WP-Blocks](http://keirwhitaker.com/archive/introducing-wp-blocks/), ([just released in beta](http://keirwhitaker.com/archive/wp-blocks-beta-download/))?